# Problem with Ruby Regular Expression

Tags: ruby, regex, web-crawler

I have this HTML code, that's on a single line:

```
<h3 class='r'><a href="www.google.com">fkdsafjldsajl</a></h3><h3 class='r'><a href="www.google.com">fkdsafjldsajl</a></h3>
```

Here is the line-friendly version (that i can't use)

```
<h3 class='r'><a href="www.google.com">fkdsafjldsajl</a></h3>
<h3 class='r'><a href="www.google.com">fkdsafjldsajl</a></h3>
```

And i'm trying to extract just the URLs, with this REGEX

```
/<h3 class="r"><a href="(.*)">(.*)<\/a>/
```

And it returns

```
www.google.com">fkdsafjldsajl</a></h3><h3 class='r'><a href="www.google.com"
```

What can I do to stop it when find a " ?

Comment: Be real careful trying to parse a HTML using regex. Even in simple HTML, you could run into a URL that messes up your regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sigh. Regex and HTML are such awkward bedfellows:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = %q{<h3 class='r'><a href="www.google.com">fkdsafjldsajl</a></h3><h3 class='r'><a href="www.google.com">fkdsafjldsajl</a></h3>}
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
puts doc.css('a').map{ |a| a['href'] }
# >> www.google.com
# >> www.google.com
```

This will find them, whether they are deeply nested or all on one line.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `*` is greedy.  Put a question mark after it to make it ungreedy.

Working regex (tested on [rubular](http://rubular.com))

```
href\=\"(.*?)\"
```

Comment: Even `(.*?)"` can eat `"`. Better use `[^"]+"`.

Comment: I don't know if the OPs use-case can encounter href's wrapped in single-quotes, but, since they are legal in HTML, the suggested pattern should probably handle those. And, since a lot of HTML is missing the wrapping double and single quotes, it should probably handle that too. Also, according to the second to last paragraph of section 2.2 of the URL [spec](http://www.apps.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.html#sec-2.2), `'` and `"` are legal within a URL so it should probably handle those too.