# how to test for a regex match

Tags: python, regex

I have a string.  Let's call it 'test'.
I want to test a match for this string, but only using the backref of a regex.

Can I do something like this:

import re

```
for line in f.readlines():
   if '<a href' in line:
      if re.match('<a href="(.*)">', line) == 'test':
         print 'matched!'
```

?
This of course, doesn't seem to work, but I would think that I might be close?
Basically the question is how can I get re to return only the backref for comparison?

Comment: I recommend [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) for developing regex -- it's a huge time saver. Here's another question where I helped someone with a similar pattern: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716787/problem-with-ruby-regular-expression

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[`re.match`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.match) matches only at the [beginning](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#matching-vs-searching) of the string.

```
def url_match(line, url):
    match = re.match(r'<a href="(?P<url>[^"]*?)"', line)
    return match and match.groupdict()['url'] == url:
```

example usage:

```
>>> url_match('<a href="test">', 'test')
True
>>> url_match('<a href="test">', 'te')
False
>>> url_match('this is a <a href="test">', 'test')
False
```

If the pattern could occur anywhere in the line, use `re.search`.

```
def url_search(line, url):
    match = re.search(r'<a href="(?P<url>[^"]*?)"', line)
    return match and match.groupdict()['url'] == url:
```

example usage:

```
>>> url_search('<a href="test">', 'test')
True
>>> url_search('<a href="test">', 'te')
False
>>> url_search('this is a <a href="test">', 'test')
True
```

N.B : If you are trying to parsing HTML using a regex, read [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/90527) before going any further.

Comment: Great.  Thanks for your reply.  How would I replace the text and write the file?

Comment: I should mention that although I read that post, it also says that you can use this method for a limited use case, which is what I have.  I don't want to build an all encompassing parser.

Comment: @jml: glad i was able to help :), for you question i don't exactly know what you mean but for replacing just use `re.sub` rather than `re.match`, and for writing to a file i think it's obvious, right ? :) you can post another question if you need more detail; like this you can have more help :)

Comment: not totally obvious to me.  :/ my experience w/ regex thus far (in other langs) has been one of a matching tool, rather than a text replacement tool.  i was not aware that the temp buffer which loads via 'r+' was modifiable.  thanks again.